# Google Colab - frequently write to a drive file

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to frequently write some data from a Colab notebook to a file located on Google Drive. I mounted the drive with the`drive.mount('/content/drive')` function. Afterwards I have a loop that is writing to a file every `n` iterations, what is implemented like:

```
for i in range(BIG):
  # Do something...
  if i % n == 0:
    with open(gdrive_file_path, "w") as f:
      f.write("Some message")
```

I noticed that if the `n` is not big enough (like `n=10`) the content is not updated and the file is overwritten after the loop's end. If the `n` is bigger (tried `n=100`) I can see the changes live. I assume that the `colab.drive` requires some operational time to have things done, but I can't find a way to ensure that the drive file is updated without stopping the loop. I hoped that `f.flush()` and `os.fsync(f)` could help, but there was no improvement, calling the `flush` method leads to writting an empty content after the loop terminatiom. Is there any way to force the full and successful frequent file upload?

Thanks for help!